# animating multiple background positions using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-position

I'm creating a toggling dropdown effect for my wordpress theme's sidebar widgets.

`h2` tags inside the widgets has two background images with different background-positions.

the css for this backgrounds is like this:

```
background-image: url(images/h2bg.png), url(images/button.png);
background-position: center left, bottom right;
background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
```

What i want to do is to animate the first background (h2bg.png) out of the element box, when the user clicks on the h2 element, and THEN change the second background image's position to `top left`. (it's a tiny sprite image)

And my jQuery script is like this: (you don't need to go through it)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebar div.widget').each(function(i) {
        height = $(this).css('height');
        $(this).attr('data-height',height);
        $(this).attr('data-animate','ON');
    });
    $('.widget h2').click(function() {
        if ($(this).parent('div.widget').attr('data-animate') == 'OFF') {
            $(this).parent('div.widget').attr('data-animate','ON');
            height = $(this).parent('div.widget').attr('data-height');
            $(this).parent('div.widget').animate({
                height: height
            },500);
            $(this).animate({
                'background-position-x': '0%, 100%'
            },500,function() {
                $(this).css('background-position-y','50%, 100%');
            });
        } else {
            $(this).parent('div.widget').attr('data-animate','OFF');
            $(this).parent('div.widget').animate({
                height: '29px'
            },500);
            $(this).animate({
                'background-position-x': '-100%, 100%'
            },500,function() {
                $(this).css('background-position-y','50%, 0%');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Long story short.. i noticed that javascript returns the `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` as percenatges with semicolons in between.

So i used percentage in animating and it worked fine for one background image. but when it comes to multiple backgrounds it doesn't work! i tried it with semicolon... without semicolon and pixel values, but no luck!

How can i handle multiple background-position properties with jQuery ?!

Answer (score 1):

you may need to redefine the image URLs in the .css/.animate methods.

```
'background-image' : 'url("image1.png"), url("image2.png")',
'background-position' : 'right 50px left 50px' (or whatever)
```

CSS uses the sequence of image-url declaration to determine which properties apply to which image, so it may be just be a case of the browser not having a point of reference (due to the styles being applied inline rather than in the stylesheet).

Also, stick to the 'background-position' declaration.  Not sure if background-position-x, background-position-y works with multiple images.

## UPDATE

jQuery can't animate a background image.  In order to get the same effect, you'd have to *fake it* by using stacked divs under the target element and resize those instead.

Comment: removing the semicolons breaks the whole thing and using `backgournd-positiond` instead of `-x` and `-y` didn't work either. without animating this code works perfectly: `background-position','-150px 0px, 255px 0px` but when i use it in `animate` function it does nothing..

Comment: After a little research, it appears as though jQuery can't actually access the necessary properties to allow 'animating' the background-image property.  I'll keep looking though.

Comment: false. jquery can animate the position of ONE background image! Example: `$('#element').animate({'background-position-x': '+=400px'}, 400);` I can't figure out how to animate two background images on the same element though...

Answer (score 0):

Just use `'background-position' : 'value px value px'` or `'left top'` or whatever works for you.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use these attributes?  It would help people who aren't as familiar with jQuery.